# tab navigation and ListActivity

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragmentactivity

In my android app I have my main activity which extends `FragmentActivity` and implements `ActionBar.TabListener`. By this I have tab navigation. I would like to have a `ListActivity` at one tab. How to do that?

I found examples where a new intent is called when the particular tab is selected. The problem with this, that as a new activity is started the tabs disappers.

Other solution to extends to different classes, like `FragmentActivity` and `ListActivity` does not seem a working.

Comment: I think what you are referring to as `ListActivity` should be a `ListFragment`.

Answer (score 0):

Well I went through this code posted on a blog and was able to create a tab navigation. It shows two different xmls. You can always modify the xmls to show exactly what you want to show, in your case a `ListView`.

[This is the link](http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-adding-actionbar-navigation-tabs.html)

Hope it helps! Cheers :)